.NET MAUI - Is it possible to enable click events on overlapping controls
I have a really specific scenario. This my code simplified:
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto" Columns="*,*">
    <custom:MyCustomView Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="0"  
        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
        HorizontalOptions="Start">
</Grid>

I have two controls inside a Grid. MyCustomView Control that have a set of clickable elements inside and a Button that will need to cover half of that View and overlap it. The idea is if the user click some on that clickable elements(buttons) on MyCustomView the dedicate command should execute, but if user have a long press, then the Big Button actions should execute. I tried everything InputTransparent and ZIndex but without any luck. Is it possible somehow this to be made in MAUI?

Did you try to add  long press interaction for the custom view?

@LiyunZhang-MSFT yes I tried. But one of the clicks is always blocked.

@LiyunZhang-MSFT I know it's a really specific UI requirement, so maybe it's not possible from MAUI perspective to be achieved

Did you want to make it work on all the platforms?

@LiyunZhang-MSFT on Android and iOS

If you want to roll your own, then, instead of implementing Clicked, implement Pressed and Released instead. Then you can build your own business logic such as setting up timers (and or using async/await on Task.Delay) for long pressed, and so forth. Once your business criteria has been met you can call a developer supplied ICommand.

Is your custom view type of ContentView? If not, you can change its type to ContentView and then the CustomView's LongPressCommand and the child view's clicked event will both work.
In addition, if you don't want to change it. You can use the platform view's long pressed event instead of the LongPressCommand. Such as:
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto" Columns="*,*">
    <custom:MyCustomView x:Name="customview" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="0"  
        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
        HorizontalOptions="Start">
</Grid>

And in the code behind:
protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
    {
        base.OnHandlerChanged();
#if ANDROID
        var view = customview.Handler.PlatformView as Android.Views.View;
        view.LongClick += (s, e) =>
        {
            // do something
        };
#elif IOS
       var view = customview.Handler.PlatformView as UIKit.UIView;
       view.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
       view.AddGestureRecognizer(new UIKit.UILongPressGestureRecognizer(HandleLongClick));
#endif
    }
   #if IOS
    private void HandleLongClick(UIKit.UILongPressGestureRecognizer sender)      
    {          
       //do something      
    }
#endif

Of course, you can put them into the MyCustomView.cs to avoid coding every time.

thank you for the advice but I want the button to have a long press and the view in behind should work with normal press. Can we modify the code like that?

You can just add the platform native long pressed event to the Button and then it will have both normal clicked event and long pressed event. @Rajzer
